# how to check input date exist in between two date column or not? nodejs sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

the date user entered is to check the date is between or exist in start_Date column and end_Date column in MySQL db. using NodeJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Sequelize to make such query then you can use `Op.gte` and `Op.lte` operators to achieve these two comparisons:

```js
const records = model.findAll({
  where: {
    start_Date: {
      [Op.lte]: date
    },
    end_Date: {
      [Op.gte]: date
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: i did this but it could not help me to check date date between two column, like user entered "2022-01-04" and start_Date column has value "2022-01-01" and end_Date column has " 2022-01-05" in YYYY-MM-DD format i am using

Comment: look at generated SQL and please add it to your post.